# Alternatives to Smart Actions for non-Motorola devices?

Tags: automation

Motorola's recent selection of Android gadgets (particularly, the Droid Razr) sport a [Smart Actions](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/SMART-ACTIONS/SMART-ACTIONS) application that automatically modifies your phone settings when certain events occur -- for example, turning off data service and ringer at night, reducing volume when you arrive at work, turn off Bluetooth and Wi-Fi when you get home, etc.

I've seen this in action on my friend's device, and by his account, this is quite a battery-saving and convenience feature.

I wonder if there exists a similar application on the Market for non-Motorola devices.

Comment: By the way. SmartActions isn't continued by Motorola and replaced by Assist with much fewer functions.

Answer (score 9):

Well, you have several applications that do what you want. You have [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&feature=search_result) which is paid, [Llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rZWJhYi5MbGFtYSJd) which is free and I'm currently using and can recommend, if you look around in the Market, you can find other applications.

Comment: +1 for llama as it uses mobile network for location rather than GPS and its free :D

Comment: actually it can use both by installing an add-on ;) https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en

Answer (score 3):

There is also the free [Timeriffic](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic&hl=en). Works similar to what I remember of [Locale](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale) but without the GPS component.

Answer (score 1):

The app that I use for this is Unlock with WiFi ([free version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwififree), [paid version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwifi)) while it can't do anywhere near as much as Tasker and Locale can, I prefer small apps that do exactly what I want and not much more.

Unlock with WiFi as well as its core function of disabling the screen lock when you're attached to a trusted Wifi point, can also switch Wifi, bluetooth, GPS and Background Sync on and off depending on whether or not you're connected to the trusted Wifi (I have my home wifi, and my parents Wifi points specified as trusted).

If you're interested in doing more than this, or triggering differently then [Locale](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale) and [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (both paid apps) are very highly recommended for automating Android settings and apps.